# sed Command between two log dates

Tags: bash

I have written the following sed line trying to only see log files between yesterday and today that have the word "ERROR" in them and returning a Simple Y / N if they are there.

I'm not actually giving me a proper return that I need.  Can someone help point me out where this is going wrong?

```
 today="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
 yesterday="$(date -d '24 hour ago' +%Y-%m-%d)"
    iserror="$(if [ sed -n "/"$yesterday"/,/"$today"/p" /mnt/data/systemlogs/logstash/logs/pipeline.log | grep "ERROR" ] = ""  ; then
    echo "No"
 else
    echo "Yes"
 fi;
)"
```

Comment: this looks relatively elegant, but what about this: 1. convert your end/start dates to unix timestamps (integer value) 2. use sed / grep to extract the date-time from each log row 3. convert said date-time to timestamp 3. use arithmetic comparison to compare with start and end 4. only output matching lines?

Comment: @Marcus Müller This is part of a rather large script I am putting together to validate information, this same thing would be repeated over 20 times to different log entries.  I assume there would be no difference in speed attempting to do it that way?

Comment: I'd suggest GNU awk with its [builtin Time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html). A bit more programming, but very efficient

Comment: If you are interested in speed, then you shouldn't be using the shell for this. Try a real programming language (the shell isn't one) instead.

Comment: terdon - there are some limitations around using "other" or "real programming" languages.  Code approval for this with python/C is horrendous.

Comment: Fair enough. But if you're working with the shell, it is a bit strange to worry about speed, that's all. If you're tied to the shell, then you will  need to accept that things will be relatively slow.

Comment: @Nathan I don't think there will be much difference to speed, but to probability of bug/error, and to systematically doing the right thing! Comparison of date-times is hard, conversion to a monotonic numerical representation is how you do it usually. The fact that this happens in 20 places suggests that putting exactly my proposal into a shell function would be a wise thing, especially in terms of lines of code that can go wrong and need approval.

Comment: (and I'd be on @terdon's side, but complaining to you will just be preaching to the choir: code review/approval should favor doing things in an appropriate language, where the problem can be solved in a concise, safe way, and not in a language that relies on everything being passed as arguments that are potentially shell-parsed... this approval process preferring bash over proper languages seems to make the average piece of approved software worse, not better)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you, I will dig a little deeper into pushing toward that right direction.  Harder when "its the norm" is used.  But appreciate the incite, didn't fall on def ears.

Comment: @Nathan you go and do the right thing :-) All the best for your code! Even if you can't convince the uppers: Best practices and norms change over time. Sometimes change is fast, sometimes it takes a bit. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong here:

```
iserror="$(if [ sed -n "/"$yesterday"/,/"$today"/p" pipeline.log | grep "ERROR" ] = ""  ; then
    echo "No"
 else
    echo "Yes"
 fi;
)"
```

The syntax for the `if [ ]` construct is `if [ condition ]`. You have `if [ command ] condition` since the `= ""` is outside the `[ ]`. Running that code should have given you a few syntax errors:

```
$ iserror="$(if [ sed -n "/"$yesterday"/,/"$today"/p" pipeline.log | grep "ERROR" ] = ""  ; then
     echo "No"
  else
     echo "Yes"
  fi;
 )"
bash: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
grep: =: No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
```

What you are attempting is this:

```
iserror="$(if [ $(sed -n "/"$yesterday"/,/"$today"/p" pipeline.log | grep "ERROR") = "" ] ; then
    echo "No"
 else
    echo "Yes"
 fi;
)"
```

But that isn't good either since if the `grep` returns nothing, you will be missing an argument and get a different error:

```
$ iserror="$(if [ $(sed -n "/"$yesterday"/,/"$today"/p" pipeline.log | grep "bERROR") = "" ] ; then
    echo "No"
 else
    echo "Yes"
 fi;
)"
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
```

Instead, you can use `grep -c` which will always return a number, 0 if there were no matches and the number of matches if there were:

```
iserror="$(if [ $(sed -n "/"$yesterday"/,/"$today"/p" pipeline.log | grep -c "ERROR") -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "No"
 else
    echo "Yes"
 fi;
)"
```

Or, simpler, use `grep -q` which produces no output but exits with success if it found something and failure if it didn't:

```
iserror="$(sed -n "/"$yesterday"/,/"$today"/p" pipeline.log | 
        grep -q "ERROR" && 
            echo Yes || 
                echo No)"
```

By the way, you could also make more use of `sed` here and have it print only if there is a match for `ERROR` in the relevant lines:

```
iserror="$(if [ $(sed -n '/2022-10-26/,/2022-10-27/{ /ERROR/p }' pipeline.log | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then 
    echo Yes; 
else 
    echo No; 
fi) "
```

Comment: Thank you!  Much easier to understand what I was doing wrong